# How to give shared layout a model in Razor MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, razor

I'm trying to give a model to the shared layout so the menu links are created dynamically from a database. Any ideas where I should start?

I am looking for maybe tutorials of how to use inheritance to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this:

**Model**

```
public partial class Menu
{
    public String[] items;

    public Menu(String[] items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

**View (_Menu)**

```
@model YourMVC.Models.Menu

<ul>
    @foreach (String item in Model.items)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
```

**Place this in _Layout**

```
@Html.Action("_Menu", "Home")
```

**Controller (HomeController)**

```
public ActionResult _Menu()
{
    String[] items = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"};

    return PartialView(new Menu(items));
}
```

Of course in your actual implementation you would grab whatever you needed from the database in the controller `_Menu()` action.

I'm not sure if this implementation is the best practice, but it certainly works.

Comment: Can I ask, why you use the partial class?

Comment: It's not necessary here, but I've often worked on projects where the models are generated by an ORM (LINQ to SQL) as `partial` classes with additional model code manually added in another file where it won't be overwritten by the ORM.